# Userform listbox filled with pivot table values - excel

Tags: vba, listbox, excel-2010, pivot-table, userform

I am trying to load a listbox with the rows from a pivot table field. I have found the following code that works for a ActiveX Control Listbox, but not for a UserForm Listbox. The UserForm control receives a 438 error. I am working with a series of UserForms and the activeX control can only be embedded in a worksheet.

```
   Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
      Dim Pf As PivotField
      Dim I As Integer
        Set Pf = Worksheets("Sheet4").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Field Name")
        With ActiveSheet.ListBox1
         .Clear
            For I = 1 To Pf.PivotItems.Count
            .AddItem Pf.PivotItems(I)
            Next
        End With
    End Sub
```

The original code was found here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/fill-listbox-values-pivot-table-field-example-t967653.html

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Someone on LinkedIn was able to answer the question, I am posting this on the off chance it helps someone else in the future:

```
   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 

   Dim pvtTable As PivotTable 
   Dim pvtField As PivotField 
   Dim lngIndex As Long 

   Set pvtTable = Worksheets("Sheet4").PivotTables(1) 
   Set pvtField = pvtTable.PivotFields("Field Name") 

  For lngIndex = 1 To pvtField.PivotItems.Count 
  UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem pvtField.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name 
  Next 

  End Sub
```

Make sure the reference Userform1 matches the name of your userform. Or use the ME keyword instead.